# AutoFit Guest not working

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

Windows 7 x64 Enterprise host with Windows 7 Enterprise (x86 or x64) guest operating systems. VMware Workstation v7.0.0.203737 configured:

AutoFit Window: No
AutoFit Guest: Yes

When VM boots up, the screen isn't resized (it's narrower and higher than the host window) and "Fit Guest Now" is greyed out. Once you have logged in, the "Fit Guest Now" option is enabled and the screen can be resized.

A bit annoying. Any idea?

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed the VMware tools on the guest operating system

If you have, it may be worth reinstalling.

After you have done this, resizing should work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, resizing does on login screen (GDM) not work with Linux guests like Ubuntu 11.04.